# Use cell data and combine in formule Apple Numbers

Tags: numbers, apple-numbers, apple-numbers-formula

I need a little help with my formule in Apple Numbers.

My sheet has a lot of data and I will make this al little bit easier.

So I create a sum.if formule see below

```
SOMMEN.ALS(Inkomsten::Tabel 1::$Bedrag exclusief BTW;Inkomsten::Tabel 1::$Datum;">=01-01-2023";Inkomsten::Tabel 1::$Datum;"<=31-01-2023";Inkomsten::Tabel 1::$BTW percentage;"=21%")
```

For this year (2024) I copied the file but the formule contains 2023.

I created a new cell with 2024 and I want use this in my formule like below

```
SOMMEN.ALS(Inkomsten::Tabel 1::$Bedrag exclusief BTW;Inkomsten::Tabel 1::$Datum;">=01-01-{YEAR}";Inkomsten::Tabel 1::$Datum;"<=31-01-{YEAR}";Inkomsten::Tabel 1::$BTW percentage;"=21%")
```

Who can help me implanted this in my formule?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution
Add a new column and use the function month in Apple Numbers. This gives a digit what you can use in the formule

```
SOMMEN.ALS(Inkomsten::Tabel 1::$Bedrag exclusief BTW;Inkomsten::Tabel 1::Maand;"=1";Inkomsten::Tabel 1::Maand;"=1";Inkomsten::Tabel 1::$BTW percentage;"=21%")
```